# Help transcribing a sentence

Tags: vocabulary

I can catch just a few words from this clip (10 sec). Would you be so kind as to help me?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13823768/sound.wma

Here's what I hear:

Reminds me of that psycho in ?. It's an homage ? in the commentary ? cinematic allusion ? I'm sure.

Comment: I heard it like this: "(Oh, that) reminds me of that psycho in, um, *Don't Look Now*." "*Don't Look Now*." "Yeah." "It's (how much.)" "How much." "How much we could smoke." "(Who's) in the commentary (with--um) like this cinematic illusion." -- I parenthesized the parts I'm less sure about, and I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: @Damkerng T. +1 for *Don't look now*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: (**?**)... reminds me of that psycho in, um--
B: *Don't look now*
A: *Don't look now.*
A: Yeah
{both laughing}
C: It's an homage
A: ...an *homage*
B: An homage <s>(*garbled something*)</s> to Nicolas Roeg
{laughing}
B: Those listening to the commentary will, will like these cinematic, uh, allusions, I'm sure...

(Credit to **Damkerng T.** for *Don't look now* and to **user18807** for *to Nicolas Roeg*).

Answer (score 3):

δοῦλος's answer is nearly complete already, but just for the last words, the 'garbled' sentence is: "An homage to Nicolas Roeg."

Comment: +1 Heh, I guess he directed *Don't look  now*. I wonder if I had looked up that movie before now if I would have heard Nicolas Roeg. I'm putting him in my answer for the sake of completeness. My post can be changed to a Community Post if that's allowable.

Comment: I actually looked up the list of directors and actors, and I couldn't make out what he was saying. Well done!